# How can I replace the selected portion of an input value?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to select a word or more words of the input and click push button to replace the selected portion of the string with an underscore.

This is not complete code but gives you the idea somehow:

```js
const blankInput = document.getElementById('blank-input');
const dictatePush = document.querySelector('.dictate-push');


dictatePush.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const start = blankInput.selectionStart;
  const finish = blankInput.selectionEnd + 1;
  blankInput.value = blankInput.value.substring(0, start) + '_';
});
```

```css
input {
  width: 50vw;
}
```

```html
<input data-collect="blank" id="blank-input" type="text" value="Select (highlight) a word and click Push">
<button type="button" class="dictate-push">Push</button>
```

So if you type `I think I might need a car` and select the `might` as a word after clicking push we should get this:

`I think I _ need a car`

1. Note that we want it clean so if you select the exact word or select
   the word and surrounding spaces we should still get the same result.
2. we want to return the replaced word too, here it's `might`

How would you do this ?

Comment: Hey is it a possible solution to have another input box, and you type the words you want blanked out?

Comment: Your question keeps getting more complicated. Apparently you want to skip blank spaces in the selection. Please revise to state that.

Comment: I did before `Note that we want it clean so if you select the exact word or select the word and surrounding spaces we should still get the same result.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include trimming of start and end of the original string, something like this:

```js
const blankInput = document.getElementById('blank-input');
const dictatePush = document.querySelector('.dictate-push');


dictatePush.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const value = blankInput.value;
  const start = blankInput.selectionStart;
  const finish = blankInput.selectionEnd;
  if(start !== finish) { //There is a selection

    const removedWord = value.substring(start, finish).trim();
    const substringStart = value.substring(0, start).trimEnd();
    const substringEnd = value.substring(finish).trimStart();
    console.log("Result:", substringStart + " _ " + substringEnd);  
    console.log("Removed Word:", removedWord);
  }

  
});
```

```html
<input data-collect="blank" id="blank-input" type="text">
<button type="button" class="dictate-push">Push</button>
```

Comment: This is missing the first word after _ (underscore)

Comment: Sorry, its now fixed

Comment: Legendary......................

Comment: I just included the removed word

Answer (score 1):

What i have done is taken the window selection, and replaced the selected bit with `_` then pushed the value back into the input box.

Once all replacements are done i then search the string for double spaces and replace with a single to give expected results.

```js
const blankInput = document.getElementById('blank-input');
const dictatePush = document.querySelector('.dictate-push');

dictatePush.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  blankInput.value = blankInput.value.replace(window.getSelection().toString(), " _ ");
  blankInput.value = blankInput.value.replace("  ", " ");
});
```

```css
input {
  width: 50vw;
}
```

```html
<input data-collect="blank" id="blank-input" type="text" value="Select (highlight) a word and click Push">
<button type="button" class="dictate-push">Push</button>
```

You can see a working codepen here:

https://codepen.io/SweetChillyPhilly/pen/YzvebPV

Comment: Thanks but all answers here give us no space between the underscore and the remaining of the string like this: `Select a _and click Push` but we want `Select a _ and click Push`

Comment: Hey @SaraRee I know im a bit late, but i have edited my answer and believe this is a cleaner solution and still gives the desired results :)